# unittest - occurs error

Tags: python

When I try run this unit test in Ninja-IDE:

```
import Node
import unittest


class TestNode(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_creation(self):
        self.testedInstance = Node(1)
        self.assertIsNotNone(testedInstance)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I get this error:

> Ran 1 test in 0.001s
>
> FAILED (errors=1)
>
> Execution Successful!

file Node.py:

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, init_value):
        self.value = init_value
```

If I change the test body to `self.assertTrue(1)`, the error disappears.

Sorry for my English.

Thanks

Comment: Did you mean `self.assertIsNotNone(self.testedInstance)` instead perhaps? No need to assign to `self` if a local name will do, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`testedInstance` is not defined. Did you mean `self.testedInstance`?

```
def test_creation(self):
    self.testedInstance = Node(1)
    self.assertIsNotNone(self.testedInstance)
```

Or did you mean to create the `Node` in local namespace?

```
def test_creation(self):
    testedInstance = Node(1)
    self.assertIsNotNone(testedInstance)
```

Comment: Not that attributes on the instance are needed here.

Comment: Then it's probably time to show us the entire error. With either of my corrections your code works for me.

Comment: After the test run is only output message that at me above. No more no information. IDE - Ninja for Ubuntu                        And I did mean first variant.

Comment: What happens if you run your script in a terminal, `python yourfilename.py`?

Comment: ERROR: test_creation (__main__.TestNode)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestNode.py", line 8, in test_creation
    self.tested = Node(1)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: Thanks. I change 'import Node' to 'import Node from Node' and test is completed successfully